# Swift3-Custom autohide UINavigationbar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I want to customise the navigation bar as follows. Can anyone give me some hints?
I'm using swift 3 and iOS > 8.0.

[image]

Comment: You have to post code you have tried first

Comment: i wanna add some code but i dont know how to start..

Answer (score 0):

Write this line in **ViewDidLoad()** method

navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true